# UIMA Ruta: Check if feature is empty/undefined

Tags: uima, ruta

Within a UIMA Ruta script, I would like to check whether a feature of an annotation has been set/defined/is not null (whatever you call it). The feature is itself not of primitive type, but an "Annotation".

Is there a way to do that so that this check can be used to restrict generation of new annotations if the feature is not set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to simply write it down in the feature dot notation with a comparison against null:

```
MyAnnotation.complexFeature != null;
a:MyAnnotation{a.complexFeature != null};
```

(requires a newer Ruta version, it should work just fine in Ruta 2.6.1)

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: is there any practical workaround for those using older version of RUTA? (e.g. 2.2.1)